# Combining 2 resultset of "Find" in soql

Tags: soql

Can we combine 2 resultset of "Find" statement. I have one field that I am searching on NAME and other fields which I am searching on ALL columns...Although my RETRIEVAL columns are same...

Please suggest.how to combine resultset...

Answer (score 6):

you can do like this -

```
// First result set
List<List<SObject>> searchList1 = search.query(SOSLQuery1);

// Second result set
List<List<SObject>> searchList2 = search.query(SOSLQuery2);
```

then

```
// Combine both result set
searchList1.add(searchList2);
```

Comment: +1 but I'd use `addAll()` and flatten it to single `List<sObject>`, not list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

SOSL reference mentions bit complex examples like [`FIND {MyProspect AND "John Smith" OR MyCompany}`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm) so if you're going through same object I suspect you could rewrite your search to a simpler form. Can you post it? Also I'm a bit unclear whether you have one or 2 separate `[FIND...]` statements.

If you want a flat list of generic sObjects coming from same search on diiferent sObjects then maybe something like this?

```
List<List<sObject>> results = [FIND 'test*' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING 
    Account (Id, Name), 
    Contact (Id, Name)];

List<sObject> flatList = results[0].addAll(results[1]);
```

So if you really want 2 searches on same object the idea would be the same, just replace my `sObject` and possibly cast the lists.